# Can we spawn more containers from existing one in a pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I am having Kubernetes pod on a machine and want to have empty pod where on run time pod should be able to add/remove the containers but seems like pod always starts with something called init_container, so can this init_container spawn more containers?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If it is scaling, I would check out Kubernetes `Deployments` and the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` but from your question it is not really clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Blokje5, I have added the more details.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible.  At an API level, the `containers` in a [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#podspec-v1-core) cannot be updated once the pod has been created.

For this sort of setup the pattern I've found more useful is to set up a job queue like RabbitMQ, and then set up some number of workers that can read from that queue and do individual jobs.  In Kubernetes land, the workers can be a simple Deployment and you can then control the number of workers with `kubectl scale`.